# How to upload file to ftp server by sim900 in AT commands(ftp session close)?

Tags: ftp, at-command, sim900

My AT Commands:

```
AT+CREG?
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"Contype","GPRS"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","mtnirancell"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"USER","xxxx"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"PWD","xxxxx"
AT+SAPBR=1,1
AT+FTPCID=1
AT+FTPSERV="yzd.ir"
AT+FTPPORT=21
AT+FTPUN="xxxx"
AT+FTPPW="xxxx"
AT+FTPPUTNAME="ehsan.txt"
AT+FTPPUTPATH="/"
AT+FTPPUT=1
AT+FTPPUT=2,10
```

server log:

```
Jul 21 13:42:36 yzd proftpd[2019] yzd (::ffff:5.116.194.141[::ffff:5.116.194.141]): FTP session opened.
Jul 21 13:42:36 yzd proftpd[2019] yzd (::ffff:5.116.194.141[::ffff:5.116.194.141]): USER xxxx: Login successful.
Jul 21 13:42:38 yzd proftpd[2019] yzd (::ffff:5.116.194.141[::ffff:5.116.194.141]): FTP session closed.
```

Comment: Please also provide the responses to all the AT commands as well (the responses to `AT+FTPPUT` will for instance be essensial to eliminate problems).

Comment: [Link to SIM900 AT Command manual](http://garden.seeedstudio.com/images/a/a8/SIM900_AT_Command_Manual_V1.03.pdf). The [official website entry](http://www.simcom.us/product_detail.php?cid=1&pid=37) only links version 1.0 (the whole web site is one of the most dysfunctional I've encountered in several years, and it appears to be somewhat barely-replaced-template-boilerplate-content. I will be shocked if this link continues to work say 5 years into the future).